How to type a ~ symbol in grammar environment of syntax package?
The MWE is like the following. It does not work.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nounderscore, rounded]{syntax}

\begin{document}
\begin{grammar}

<range> ::= <digit> `~' <digit>

<range> ::= <digit> ~ <digit> % added by MS-SPO

\end{grammar}
\end{document}

(Added by MS-SPO) 
The document does not tell the solution.


What do you mean "It does not work"?

It's true, the tilde is not displayed if you use it alone. However: where do you get the package and its documentation from? It doesn't seem to be available via ctan ... https://ctan.org/topic/syntax ?

@Jack Can you show a screenshot of what you get? If I try your code, I get a tilde https://i.sstatic.net/YFFIZoix.png

@MS-SPO https://ctan.org/pkg/mdwtools

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, thank you, jsut found it on my system ... 1996 ...

@MS-SPO https://ctan.org/pkg/syntax-mdw Here is the doc on ctan.

@MS-SPO Why is your tilde centered, but mine is on the top?

@JackMa They probably compile with lualatex or xelatex

@JackMa If you want a centred tilde in pdflatex, try with \usepackage{lmodern} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you. It truly works. But it also changes the font of the whole article. I only want it to work in the grammar environment.

Please avoid “it does not work” and try to clearly explain what actually goes wrong.
The package doesn't tell the truth. The meaning of ~ inside the grammar environment is the same as usual, unless between quotes.
If you want a centered (small) tilde, you can do as follows.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nounderscore, rounded]{syntax}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\smallsim}{%
  $\m@th\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\sim$}}$%
}
\renewcommand{\ulitleft}{%
  \normalfont\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont
  \syn@ttspace\frenchspacing
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginEnvironment{grammar}{%
  \let~\smallsim
}

\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}
<range> ::= <digit> `~' <digit>

<range> ::= <digit> ~ <digit>
\end{grammar}

\end{document}


Caveat. The syntax package is a clever collection of hacks. I just added one.

+1 Nice solution, as always

Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry I didn't make myself clear. What I want is a centered tilde as a terminal in the grammar environment. But in the current result, it is on the top.

@JackMa I don't know what a “terminal”. The syntax package is very convoluted and I see no way to do what you seem to want. Between quotes, ~ is set to an “other character” and thus you just get what the font provides at the slot.

A terminal means something between quotes. I want the centered tilde surrounded by quotes. Are there any tricks?
Others tell a solution.   \usepackage{lmodern}  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
But it also changes the font of the whole article. I only want the centered ~ quoted in the grammar environment.
Thanks for all your help!!

@JackMa WOW! That's a great hint! See edited answer.

@egreg Nice solution!! Thanks! Maybe I should learn more tricks of tex, is there any docs or tutorials to learn advanced tex skills? I really want to be a Tex magician like you!

For the terminal question you can replace \vcenter{} in @egreg's approach (before his recent edit) by \raisebox{}{} and adjust the vertical raise by eye. Mine seems to work with \raisebox{+0.8pt}{}. Try different values.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nounderscore, rounded]{syntax}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\smallsim}{%
  $\m@th\raisebox{+0.8pt}{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\sim$}}$%
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginEnvironment{grammar}{\let~\smallsim}

\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}
<range> ::= <digit> `~' <digit>

<range> ::= <digit> ~ <digit>
\end{grammar}

\end{document}


Thanks for your help!!!
